# Maintain CSS styling from a js.erb file that updates the page with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ajax

I have an up/down vote mechanism that is updated via ajax. Originally, the code in my view to display the vote count was: `<p id='votes'><%= pluralize video.vote_sum, 'Vote' %></p>` and the code in my create.js.erb file was: `$('selector').html("<p id='votes'><%= escape_javascript pluralize(@video.vote_sum, 'Vote') %></p>");`

However, I realized I wanted to have different CSS styling for the number generated from `<%= pluralize video.vote_sum, 'Vote' %>` than that for the text "Vote" or "Votes". This required me changing the view code to:

```
<p id='votes'>
    <%= video.vote_sum %>
    <div class="vote_text">
    <% word = "Vote" %>
    <% if video.vote_sum != 1 %>
      <%= word.pluralize %>
    <% else %>
      <%= word %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</p>
```

which works fine. However, when I changed the JS code to this:

```
$('selector').html("<p id='votes'>
  <%= video.vote_sum %>
    <div class="vote_text">
    <% word = "Vote" %>
    <% if video.vote_sum != 1 %>
      <%= word.pluralize %>
    <% else %>
      <%= word %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</p>");
```

the vote display stops updating. Now voting works and all, because when I refresh the page, it displays the correct vote count with the correct styling. However, the ajax has stopped working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unescaped quotation marks in that JavaScript string. Also, multi-line strings in JavaScript need some special markup — a `\` at the end of each non-terminating line.

Fixed:

```
$('selector').html("<p id='votes'> \
  <%= video.vote_sum %> \
    <div class=\"vote_text\"> \
    <% word = "Vote" %> \
    <% if video.vote_sum != 1 %> \
      <%= word.pluralize %> \
    <% else %> \
      <%= word %> \
    <% end %> \
    </div> \
</p>");
```

Comment: Oh, I missed something! Multi-line strings in JavaScript need escapes. I'll update the code. (déjà vu much? :P )

Comment: Could you post it on jsFiddle maybe, so I could debug it myself?

Comment: hmm, there would be a lot of stuff to reproduce. Would you mind forking my code?

Comment: That's fine, where can I access it?

Comment: I can't find a page where that JS code is included. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Yes, but what is the path to a front-end page that is supposed to include and use that code?

Comment: I checked that page, and I don't see that JS file being loaded.

Comment: What do you mean? It's true that the ajax rendering is not working right now, but the file is called in the create method of the video_vote controller. If you change the create.js.erb file to what it originally was (see the top of the question details) you will see that it works, but with incorrect styling.

Comment: I'm confused.. I am on `/videos` and do not see the code from `create.js.erb` anywhere in the HTML or in the loaded scripts.

Comment: create.js.erb is called when you vote. You can vote by clicking one of the blue buttons with the arrows in them.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to use `@video` in your view — an error was being thrown because the variable `video` was not set.

Comment: Ahh, right, right. I thought I fixed that at some point :/ The ajax still shouldn't work silently

Comment: Oh ok, now I just realized what's probably happening to you. You have to be authorized before you can vote. Go to `/users/new` to create an account. Then go to `/login` to login. Then proceed to `/videos`. Sorry!!!

Comment: Yes, I created a user and logged in. With that fix I mentioned the code works for me, or am I missing something? The vote count goes up by 1 when I click the up arrow.

Comment: Ok, but does the styling of the elements in #vote_display stay the same with the ajax update??

Comment: I just edited the js.erb to use `@videos` that's all. Could your git copy be ahead of the remote master branch? Maybe you made a change after your last push that I don't have.

Comment: No, I pushed to git right before sending you the link... Maybe there was something wrong with my cache? Unfortunately I'm not currently at my computer with the code so I won't be able to check for a bit

Comment: ahhh it works now! I think it was that I had forgotten to change `video` to `@video` after I had added in the escapes. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Good luck with your Rails app!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').html("<p id='votes'> "+
"<%= video.vote_sum %> "+
  "<div class=\"vote_text\"> "+
    "<% word = "Vote" %> "+
       "<% if video.vote_sum != 1 %> "+
           "<%= word.pluralize %> "+
        "<% else %> "+
           "<%= word %> "+
       "<% end %> "+
   "</div> "+
 "</p>");
```

I got this solved this way...it works fine if you use JS type join

Hope this helps